# How to load my json data into a html table and make the rows as radio buttons using pure Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json

I have a json response:

```
var jsondata = dojo.fromJson(response);
```

I have a string

```
var jsonString = jsondata.items;
```

jsonString is the JSON file

```
jsonString="[
                {macAddress:'aa:bb:Cc',domainName:'NMS',Priority:'first'},
                {macAddress:'ea:fb:Ca',domainName:'Network',Priority:'third'}, 
                {macAddress:'ca:bb:Ca',domainName:'Mesh',Priority:'second'}
            ]";
```

Now I want to access the first object `{macAddress:'aa:bb:Cc',domainName:'NMS',Priority:'first'}` by `jsonString[0]`. 
**This is not working**. This displays "[", which is the first element and not the first object.

I have also tried

```
jsondata.items[0];
jsondata[Object.keys(jsondata)[0]];
jsondata[1];
```

Everything says "Undefined".

Could someone please help?I need to extract this data and put it in a table with rows as radio buttons

Comment: you need to `JSON.parse()` a JSON string before you can use it like a plain ol' javascript array/object

Comment: Why should I parse? I am not writing a jsonResonse. I am getting the jsonResonse from backend.

Comment: You still need to use `JSON.parse()`. As stated, without a parse, JavaScript treats it as a string, so calling `jsondata.items[0]` will attempt to grab the first letter of that string.

Comment: `jsonString` is a string ... a JSON string ... it's just a string .. it has no objects, it isn't an array ... you need to `var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);` ... then `obj[0].macAddress` will be `'aa:bb:Cc'`

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX @Obsidian Age. I am getting the below error: 
 `JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data` Even though I am not missing any '}'

Comment: Hey guys I figured it out. :) 
I have used the below code to access the first object: 
`dojo.fromJson(jsondata.items)[0]`

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an error in your `json` string, try to validate `json` using [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com)

Please find the working code below :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var jsonString = '[{"macAddress": "aa:bb:Cc","domainName": "NMS","Priority": "first"},{"macAddress": "ea:fb:Ca","domainName": "Network","Priority": "third"},{"macAddress": "ca:bb:Ca","domainName": "Mesh","Priority": "second"}]'; 

    var row = '';     
 
    $.each($.parseJSON(jsonString), function(index, value){
        row += '<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="radio" name="test" /> '+ value.macAddress +'</td></tr>';
  });
    $('#tbl tbody').html(row);
});
```

```html
 <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Stackoverflow</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="container">
  <table id="tbl">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>&nbsp;</th>
     <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Debasish. I will try this. But I wanted this in javascript and not jquery.
I have also tried validating my json. It is valid. The json string which I have mentioned is just a sample.

Comment: check this fiddle, code is modified to javascript [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/35eqwh7k/)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var jsonString = '[{"macAddress": "aa:bb:Cc","domainName": "NMS","Priority": "first"},{"macAddress": "ea:fb:Ca","domainName": "Network","Priority": "third"},{"macAddress": "ca:bb:Ca","domainName": "Mesh","Priority": "second"}]';

var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);

//build head
var head = '<tr>';

for(key in jsonObject[0]){
    head +='<th>&nbsp;</th><th>'+key+'</th>';
}
head +='</tr>';

//build rows

var rows = jsonObject.map(function(element){
            var row = '<tr>';
            for( key in element){
                row += '<td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="radio" name="'+key+'" /> '+ element[key] +'</td>';    
            }
            row += '</tr>';
            return row;
         });

//adding to table
var tbl_head = document.getElementById('tbl').getElementsByTagName('thead')[0];
var tbl_body = document.getElementById('tbl').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

tbl_head.innerHTML = head;
tbl_body.innerHTML = rows.join('');
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Stackoverflow</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <table id="tbl">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
   </table>
  </div>            
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Juan. But I wanted this is javascript with no jquery :(